# Como puedo hacer una inserción en tablas relacionadas mediante un web service

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando una aplicación para android con conexión a una base de datos mysql con web service php. Funciona todo perfecto pero necesito una querrá que no soy capaz de sacar. Os pongo en situación; tengo dos tablas usuarios (id (AI), nombre, correo) y coches (id(AI), modelo, id_usuario). Las dos tablas están relacionadas por el id del usuario en relación 1 a 1.

En la aplicación el usuario rellena un formulario con su nombre correo y modelo del coche. Tal y como lo tengo planteado al evitar el formulario se ejecuta la siguiente sentencia:

Insert INTO usuarios (nombre, correo) VALUES (dato_introducido,dato_introducido)

Esta query funciona perfectamente pero quiero que también se agregue a la tabla coche con la relación. Utilizó php y mysql

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado con el siguiente codigo

```
$comando = 'INSERT INTO coche (marca, modelo, kilometros, usuario_id) SELECT ?,?,?,(SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE email = ?)';
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución. ¿Podrías elaborar un poco más tu respuesta explicando, por ejemplo, como funciona tu consulta? Recuerda además que en 48 horas puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, busca este símbolo debajo del marcador de votos: ✅

Comment: perdón por no responder, no suelo entrar a SO en las tardes, sólo lo hago por la mañana (en mi país a la hora que te respondí era mediodía) explica que hace la consulta, para que cuando alguien tenga un problema similar al tuyo, pueda entender el porqué de tu consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que puedes hacer una consulta similar a esta:

```
Insert INTO usuarios (nombre, correo) VALUES (dato_introducido,dato_introducido)
Insert INTO Cocher (modelo, id_usuario) VALUES (dato_modelo,(select top 1 id(Al) from usuarios order by id(Al) desc));
```

El primer insert es el que habías dado en el ejemplo, el segundo, inserta los datos que envías por código, y para el ID, realiza una búsqueda del último ID de la tabla de usuarios (lógicamente es el del primer insert) y lo utiliza para insertarlo en el registro, espero y te sirva.

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho y funciona perfectamente en la consola SQL pero cuando lo paso a php es como si la select de dentro del INSERT no funcionase, este es el código que he utilizado:

$comando = "INSERT INTO coche ( " .
            "marca,".
            " modelo,".
            " kilometros,".
            " usuario_id)".
            " VALUES( ?,?,?,(SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE email = ?))";